# How to use text-indent only with element not ont it's :before Selector?

Tags: html, css

If we gives the `text-indent` property on any html element then why it's also change the position of `:before` selector of that element

here I want to hide the anchor tags value but don't want `a:before`', Is it possible in css, if yes then how?

```
<a>Hello</a>

a{
    text-indent:-9999px; 
    display:block;
}
a:before{
    content:"before";
    text-indent:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can only think of this

```css
a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: inline-block; /* feels better - depends on your requirement*/
}
a:before {
  content: "before";
  text-indent: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<a>Hello</a>
```